# Procedure or function 'ProcedureName ' expects parameter 'DateParameter', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report and assigning a procedure with parameters as its data source. I'm getting this error:

Error:

> Procedure or function 'sp_sale_report ' expects parameter '@SDate', which was not supplied

Code :

```
ReportDocument rprt = new ReportDocument();

rprt.Load(@"C:\Users\Zia Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\lol\lol\Report\CrystalReport2.rpt");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Sale_Report", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleID", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds, "Data_Table1");

rprt.SetDataSource(ds);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rprt;
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the parameter `@SaleID` only. It should be `@SDate`.

Change to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDate", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: No. you are passing the Parameter name as SaleID only. It should be SDate Right ?

Comment: If you have only one paramter and its SDate means change SaleID to SDate. If SaleID as a paramter means, add a new cmd.Paramters for SDate.